# Spring Boot JPA - the filter of the mapping is ignored

Tags: java, web-services, jpa, spring-boot, hibernate-mapping

I can not find a solution for my problem.

the Problem:
I have 2 tables. in the first table projects are saved.
the second table stores which user is allowed to access the project.

I would like to have a list of all projects now. But only projects for those in the
api__user_permissions_mn at least one entry exists.

in SQL it would look like this:

> SELECT * FROM projekte 
>   INNER JOIN api__user_permissions_mn 
>   ON (api__user_permissions_mn.user_id = 35 AND  api__user_permissions_mn.projekt_id = projekte.ID);

My first problem is, the UserID (api__user_permissions_mn.user_id = 35) must be read from the OAuth login, the filter refers to the current user!

my second problem seems to be that i am not making the connection between project and permission correct.

in my testcase (UserID 35) i have 1 Project with 2 Permissions
i become back 1 Projekt with all permissions of the Database.

the filter on the user ID does not seem to work or it will be ignored!

```
"apiUserPermissions": [
            {
                "mappingId": {
                    "userID": 114,
                    "permissionID": 9,
                    "projectID": 0
                }
            },
            {
                "mappingId": {
                    "userID": 103,
                    "permissionID": 9,
                    "projectID": 0
                }
            },
            {
                "mappingId": {
                    "userID": 4,
                    "permissionID": 10,
                    "projectID": 0
                }
            },
            {
                "mappingId": {
                    "userID": 41,
                    "permissionID": 13,
                    "projectID": 0
                }
            },
```

**The Project Model:**

```
package com.microservice.api.models;

import java.sql.Date;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

import org.junit.Ignore;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.security.core.annotation.AuthenticationPrincipal;

import com.microservice.api.repository.ApiUserPermissionsRepository;

import net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.annotation.IgnoreForBinding;


@Entity
@Table(name = "projekte")
public class ProjectModel 
{

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ProjectModel.class);

    @Id
    @NotNull
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "ID",  nullable = false)
    private int projectID;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "name",  nullable = false)
    private String  name;


    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "mappingId.projectID" , cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<ApiUserPermissionsModel> apiUserPermissions = new HashSet<ApiUserPermissionsModel>();

    public int getProjectID() 
    {
        return projectID;
    }

    /**
     * <b>set the project ID</b>
     * 
     * @param id
     */
    public void setProjectID(int id) 
    {
        this.projectID = id;
    }

    /**
     * <b>get the name of the project</b>
     * 
     * @return project name
     */
    public String getName() 
    {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     * <b>set the project name</b>
     * 
     * @param name
     */
    public void setName(String name) 
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Set<ApiUserPermissionsModel> getApiUserPermissions() {
        return apiUserPermissions;
    }

    public void setApiUserPermissions(Set<ApiUserPermissionsModel> apiUserPermissions) {
        this.apiUserPermissions = apiUserPermissions;
    }

}
```

**The apiUserPermissions Model**

```
package com.microservice.api.models;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Embeddable;
import javax.persistence.EmbeddedId;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;


@Entity
@Table(name = "api__user_permissions_mn")
public class ApiUserPermissionsModel
{
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ApiUserPermissionsModel.class);

    @EmbeddedId
    private PermissionMappingId mappingId;

    public PermissionMappingId getMappingId() {
        return mappingId;
    }

    public void setMappingId(PermissionMappingId mappingId) 
    {
        this.mappingId = mappingId;
    }

    @Embeddable
    public static class PermissionMappingId implements Serializable
    {
        //@Id
        @Column(name = "user_id",  nullable = false)
        private long userID ;
        //@Id
        @Column(name = "permission_id",  nullable = false)
        private long permissionID ;
        //@Id

        @Column(name = "projekt_id",  nullable = false)
        private long projectID;

        public long getUserID() {
            return userID;
        }
        public void setUserID(long userID) {
            this.userID = userID;
        }
        public long getPermissionID() {
            return permissionID;
        }
        public void setPermissionID(long permissionID) {
            this.permissionID = permissionID;
        }
        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "projectID")
        public long getProjectID() {
            return projectID;
        }
        public void setProjectID(long projectID) {
            this.projectID = projectID;
        }
    }


}
```

```
**user.getId()**
```

this works fine, but the query dont work!
i have debuged that, the right ID is incomming (35) !!!

The Project Controller:

```
package com.microservice.api.controller;

import java.util.Set;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.annotation.AuthenticationPrincipal;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.microservice.api.models.ApiUserModel;
import com.microservice.api.models.ProjectModel;
import com.microservice.api.repository.ProjectRepository;

import io.swagger.annotations.ApiOperation;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/projects")
public class ProjectController 
{

    @Autowired
    private ProjectRepository projectDAO;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ApiOperation(value = "finds all projects for the current user",
    notes = "Only those projects are returned for which the current user is "
          + "also activated. Returns an empty list for users without project "
          + "assignment.",
    response = ProjectModel.class,
    responseContainer = "List")
    public Set<ProjectModel> getPojectsForCurrentUser(@AuthenticationPrincipal ApiUserModel user)
    {
        Set<ProjectModel> projectM = projectDAO.findByApiUserPermissions_mappingid_UserID(user.getId());
        return projectM;
    }
}
```

and the last, 
**The Project Repository**

```
package com.microservice.api.repository;

import java.util.Set;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import com.microservice.api.models.ProjectModel;

@Transactional
public interface ProjectRepository extends JpaRepository<ProjectModel, Long>
{
    @Query("SELECT p FROM ProjectModel p JOIN p.apiUserPermissions aup WHERE aup.mappingId.userID = :uid") 
    Set<ProjectModel> findByApiUserPermissions_mappingid_UserID(@Param("uid") long uid);
}
```

I have really tried many things.
I also read a lot about Hibernate, JPA and Spring Boot, but nowhere have I found a solution to the problem.
Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

***Thanks in advance***

Answer (score 0):

You should first implement UserDetailsService in your custom UserDetailsService class and the overriden

```
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username)
```

method should return your custom User class where you keep your User object.

After that you should register this UserDetailsService implementation in  your configuration implementation class which implements AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter as

```
 @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager).userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }
```

You

For getting current user id ,
You can get it from :

```
Authentication authentication =SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication());
User currentUser=(User) authentication.getPrincipal()
long id=currentUser.getId();
```

Also you should note that User class here I used must implement UserDetails interface and you should put it to your principal

I didn't understand the second question but for first question you can enable pre post authorization with adding 
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, prePostEnabled = true) annotation to your configuration and than for your method in repository:

Here I am assuming your principal has id property for getting current user id:

```
@PreAuthorize("#uid == authentication.principal.id")
Set<ProjectModel> findByApiUserPermissions_mappingid_UserID(@Param("uid") long uid);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I can not say if I made a mistake while mapping the models or if the query is wrong.